# Decision Structure for Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with the following assignment:

> Create a program that prompts the user to enter two values: a movie rating and his or her age. Using a decision structure, determine whether the user would be allowed to see the movie in a theater based on the rating and age entered. Finally, display the result of this decision to the user.

Here is my code, I did the Alt+Shift+F in NetBeans before I posted this:

```
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package age;

    /**
     *
     * @author Jason
     */
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Age {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);


            String user_age;
            System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
            user_age = user_input.next();

            String mrating;
            System.out.print("Enter the movie rating: ");
            mrating = user_input.next();

        }

    {  
        if ( user_age < 13 + mrating = G);{
        System.out.print( "You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else{
        System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        }

        if ( user_age >= 13 + mrating = PG13);{
        System.out.print( "You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else{
        System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        }

        if ( user_age >= 17 + mrating = R);{
        System.out.print( "You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else{
        System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        } 

    }
}
```

If I move my end bracket for Age up to before the `if` statements start. I can get the display to ask the age and rating of the user then the program ends with no results. If I leave the bracket there, the program errors out completely. I am new to Java and am so confused, I've been working on this for hrs with the book and websites, but I'm starting to get confused. Also, the `user_age` and `mrating` are getting an error saying variable is not used.

Comment: You have a block of code in your class that is not referencing variables that have not been declared. And in that block multiples of your if statements have dangling semicolons - e.g (`if ( user_age < 13 + mrating = G);{`). Is this your real code?

Comment: Note that the first closing brace is indented to line up with your `main()` method. This means that the `if` statements are not in that method. Remove that brace and the following opening brace and do Alt-Ctrl-F again.

Comment: @Perception There is no problem with "*not* referencing variables that have *not* been declared".

Comment: @Code-Guru - sure there is, the entire block with the if statements is entirely outside of the main method where the `user_age` and other variables are declared.

Comment: @Perception So the OP *is* referencing undeclared variables, which certainly is a problem and causes compiler errors. However, *not* referencing a variable (declared or not) doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: @Code-Guru - oh gotcha. Yes, there is a typo in my first comment. Thanks for pointing that out even though I'm sure my meaning is clear from the following context.

Comment: @Perception Yes, I understood what you meant. I added the italics to point out the typo...probably from editing your comment as you composed it...I do that all the time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot compare a `String` (e.g. `user_age`) to an integer.  Use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert to an `int` before comparing to another integer.

Second, you should not use `==` to compare two string values.  Use the `equals` method to compare two string values.

Third, use the `&&` boolean operator to represent "and" in your conditions, not `+`.

Fourth, remove the semicolon that immediately follows the condition for each of your if statements.  Otherwise, the compiler will think that `;` is the block to execute if the condition is true.

There may be other errors; these are the first 4 I found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all of your code is inside the `main()` method. This is one reason for using Alt-Ctrl-F to format your code. If you check the braces in your code, you will see that `main()` ends before the `if` statements. You can fix this by removing the closing and opening braces just before your `if` statements.

There may also be other problems in your code. If you need help fixing them, please post the full compiler error so that we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is assignment, i would not help completely....you have to ensure logical correctness of your program now...

I have resolved all compilations errors...lots of syntactical issue... please go through some beginner java book.

below would get you started...

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package age;

/**
 *
 * @author Jason
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        int user_age = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());

        String mrating;
        System.out.print("Enter the movie rating: ");
        mrating = user_input.next();

        if (user_age < 13 && mrating == "G")
        {
            System.out.print("You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        }

        if (user_age >= 13 && mrating == "PG13")
        {
            System.out.print("You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        }

        if (user_age >= 17 && mrating == "R")
        {
            System.out.print("You are of the right age for this movie");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(" You are not of correct age for this movie");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Explaining what the OP can do is much more valuable than just posting code without an explanation, especially when he doesn't understand what's going on.

Comment: I agree with you @adchilds ... just that there were too many syntax errors..too much effort in pointing out in words....probably he would understand some and not some...so best way i though would be to give the syntactically correct code so as he can compare and know what was wrong...